# Run ImageJ scripts in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, imagej

I am an average ImageJ user who learnt to write IJ.macro and Groovy by trial and error. I did this mainly using the plain a simple script editor within ImageJ. I recently came up with IntelliJ, an amazing IDE with auto-completion and debugger. With the help of google, I was able to include the ImageJ jars, and pluggings accessible as external libraries/modules so that I can use the mentioned functionalities [by adding the path in File>Project Structure>Libraries>"+">Java>... here I selected the folders with the Jars and plugins of ImageJ].

I am, therefore, optimistic that I could achieve the last step. Rather than writing the code in IntelliJ and run with the ImageJ script tool, I was wondering if it could be possible to run a script (say with Groovy or Jython) directly from IntelliJ. Somethin like calling ImageJ when I click run. Maybe changing the Java Run Environment, or using it as VM.

Before finishing, sorry if I am saying something really odd or non-sense. I am an average Joe learning by trying.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this GitHub project:

https://github.com/haesleinhuepf/run_jython_scripts_from_ide

It explains the steps required to run a script from within the IDE by starting up and using ImageJ. The tutorial focuses on Jython, but is applicable to all [supported scripting languages](https://imagej.net/Scripting#Supported_languages).

---

In general, questions about ImageJ usage and script development are best asked on the [Image.sc forum](https://forum.image.sc/) instead of here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ImageJ, but I guess your question is independent of ImageJ :-)

I you use ImageJ from java, you will have a class with a main method. Just right-click on the class and then "run" on the menu which appeared.

After your program has finished, there is a "run"-icon in the upper left corner of the small window which appeared.

I guess that's already close to running a script.

Groovy would be a better starting point for scripting (since it is partly a scripting language). You can code Groovy with the IntelliJ community edition, but for full support you need the ultimate edition. So I guess the groovy console is only available in the ultimate edition...

All other options I am aware of will not give you the auto-completion and only a poor-man's debugger (println)

Hope that helps

Comment: Running Groovy directly from within IntelliJ wouldn't help, since Groovy scripts developed for ImageJ will likely use additional functionality brought in by [SciJava](https://imagej.net/SciJava), e.g. [script parameters](https://imagej.net/Script_Parameters).

Comment: if they are available as java libs, they could be added as dependencies. But I guess, the way you are stating this, the ImageJ app uses Groovy to execute scripts against on-java dependencies... doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if people still struggle with this, it is now 3.5 years later, but if you start a script with this:

```
//@ ImagePlus myImp
import ij.ImagePlus
ImagePlus myImp = myImp
```

You can use both the autocomplete of IntelliJ and the SciJava script parameters. I keep the same script file open in both ImageJ and IntelliJ. After a change in IntelliJ, I go to the script editor to run it. It automatically detects something has changed and will ask to update.

This is a bit of a hassle, but I haven't found how to get IntelliJ to execute the script in a running instance of ImageJ.